# compiling error runaway agrument embedding audio

Tags: media9

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{media 9}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{First section}
Your text goes here.
\subsection{A subsection}
More text.

\includemedia[
addressource=eli.mp3,
flashvars={
source=eli.mp3
&autoPlay=true
},
transparent
]{\color{blue}\framebox[0.4\linewidth][c]{Arq. Elizabeth}{APlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

There are two typos in your code:

1. not `addressource` but `addresource`
2. missing `}` in

   ```
   ]{\color{blue}\framebox[0.4\linewidth][c]{Arq. Elizabeth}{APlayer.swf}
   ```

   which must read

   ```
   ]{\color{blue}\framebox[0.4\linewidth][c]{Arq. Elizabeth}}{APlayer.swf}
   ```

Comment: Not to mention `\usepackage{media 9}` (with a space).

Comment: @egreg: Believe it or not, the space in `\usepackage{media 9}` doesn't harm.

Comment: I know, but I wouldn't consider it ‘best practice’.

Comment: @egreg Of course :).